# Starting background service in new thread freezes main application

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm using a button to start a background service in my app. This is the code I'm using:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent action) {
    if (action.getActionCommand().equals("Start")) {
        while (true) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("Started");
                }
            }).start();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This does update the service every second, which it what I want. Problem is it freezes the rest of the application. How do I implement it so that that doesn't happen?

Comment: Did you forget the `android` tag?

Answer (score 1):

The following is likely to cause your application to pause:

```
    while (true) {
        ...
    }
```

Try removing those lines.

Edit: as per comment, to make the newly-launched thread fire every second, move the sleep and while loop inside the run() method:

```
if (action.getActionCommand().equals("Start")) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Started");        }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
       }
   }).start();
}
```

Comment: Removing that `while` will no yield the result he wants and you don't provide an alternate solution.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling this method in the Thread that updates the GUI, and this you're pausing the GUI refresh. Spawn a new thread and execute that there.

Answer (score 0):

an infinite loop ??
`while (true) {.....}`

how you supposed to get out of here - 
add an print statement inside loop and you will come to know that you have been stuck here after button click

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it. Here's what I should have done:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent action) {
    if (action.getActionCommand().equals("Start")) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    System.out.println("Started");
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```